# Get array result then pair with database

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to pass the array value with the database column but the result always is null. In my database already have id and ref_num column.

Schema table

```
Schema::create('products', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('ref_num', 50);
});
```

code

```
$items = Input::get('ref_num');

$ref_nums      = array_unique(array_pluck($items, 'ref_num'));
$ref_num_array = Product::whereIn('ref_num', $ref_nums)->lists('id', 'ref_num');
```

Result returned

```
$items = [ 
           [
             "ref_num" => "12345"
           ]
         ]
$ref_nums = [0 => 12345]
$ref_num_array = []
```

Expect result

```
$ref_num_array = [12345 => 1001]
```

I also tried this

```
$ref_num_array = DB::table('products')->whereIn('ref_num', $ref_nums)->lists('id', 'ref_num');
```

It returned the expected result but I get error "no query results for model".
In addition, I use `trait` in my Product Model.

Comment: Can you post more info sa we can reproduce and work on it? whats the output of $items?

Comment: Are you using `Laravel-4`?, If not, so use `pluck` instead of `lists` for `Laravel-5`.

Comment: I'm using Laravel 4.2

Comment: @KlightGarden Test if `get` works instead of `lists`.

Comment: Show us `products` table's schema.

Comment: @ako the `get ` doesn't work.